# Appcrash KERNELBASE.dll error when I try to use Microsoft Office in Docker Container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, ms-office, windows-server-2016

I’m building a Docker Windows container with Microsoft Office 2013 using following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

## Setup package management.
ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression=false
RUN powershell -Command "iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex; Install-PackageProvider -Name chocolatey -Force"

## Installing office
RUN powershell choco install officeproplus2013 --version 15.0.4827 -y

ENTRYPOINT powershell
```

When I try to create Microsoft Word COM object from Powershell console

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
```

I get following error after 30 seconds:

```
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
At line:1 char:9
+ $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

The same command works fine when I install Office in the same way and try to execute it on the virtual machine created from Windows Server 2016 Base image on AWS.

In Windows Event log I see following records in Application logname:

```
Message            : Fault bucket 108441132345, type 1                                                                                                
                     Event Name: APPCRASH                                                                                                             
                     Response: Not available                                                                                                          
                     Cab Id: 0                                                                                                                        

                     Problem signature:                                                                                                               
                     P1: WINWORD.EXE                                                                                                                  
                     P2: 15.0.4569.1504                                                                                                               
                     P3: 52c5eccd                                                                                                                     
                     P4: KERNELBASE.dll                                                                                                               
                     P5: 10.0.14393.206                                                                                                               
                     P6: 57dace38                                                                                                                     
                     P7: c06d007e                                                                                                                     
                     P8: 000da732                                                                                                                     
                     P9:                                                                                                                              
                     P10:                                                                                                                             

                     Attached files:                                                                                                                  
                     \\?\C:\Windows\Temp\WER44FE.tmp.csv                                                                                              
                     \\?\C:\Windows\Temp\WER450F.tmp.txt                                                                                              

                     These files may be available here:                                                                                               
                     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_WINWORD.EXE_3ff88aa40f6b7d16af04dad69537b6eb893d5_9d40f520_e5f6451e  

                     Analysis symbol:                                                                                                                 
                     Rechecking for solution: 0                                                                                                       
                     Report Id: facfa21b-edbb-402e-8916-3fbbcfe06244                                                                                  
                     Report Status: 4104                                                                                                              


                     EventID            : 1001
MachineName        : b68a674c1cba
Data               : {}
Index              : 418
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
EntryType          : Information
Message            : Fault bucket , type 0
                     Event Name: APPCRASH
                     Response: Not available
                     Cab Id: 0


                     Problem signature:
                     P1: WINWORD.EXE
                     P2: 15.0.4569.1504
                     P3: 52c5eccd
                     P4: KERNELBASE.dll
                     P5: 10.0.14393.206
                     P6: 57dace38
                     P7: c06d007e
                     P8: 000da732
                     P9:
                     P10:


                     Attached files:


                     These files may be available here:
                     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_WINWORD.EXE_3ff88aa40f6b7d16af04dad69537b6eb893d5_9d40f520_ae0a41f1


                     Analysis symbol:
                     Rechecking for solution: 0
                     Report Id: facfa21b-edbb-402e-8916-3fbbcfe06244
                     Report Status: 4100
                     Hashed bucket:
Source             : Windows Error Reporting
ReplacementStrings : {, 0, APPCRASH, Not available...}
InstanceId         : 1001
TimeGenerated      : 12/5/2016 1:52:26 PM
TimeWritten        : 12/5/2016 1:52:26 PM
UserName           :
Site               :
Container          :








EventID            : 1000                                                                                                                                                                                         
MachineName        : b68a674c1cba                                                                                                                                                                                 
Data               : {}                                                                                                                                                                                           
Index              : 417                                                                                                                                                                                          
Category           : Application Crashing Events                                                                                                                                                                  
CategoryNumber     : 100                                                                                                                                                                                          
EntryType          : Error                                                                                                                                                                                        
Message            : Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 15.0.4569.1504, time stamp: 0x52c5eccd                                                                                                      
                     Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.206, time stamp: 0x57dace38                                                                                                        
                     Exception code: 0xc06d007e                                                                                                                                                                   
                     Fault offset: 0x000da732                                                                                                                                                                     
                     Faulting process id: 0x5ae4                                                                                                                                                                  
                     Faulting application start time: 0x01d24efecf6dbf33                                                                                                                                          
                     Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE                                                                                                      
                     Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll                                                                                                                                     
                     Report Id: facfa21b-edbb-402e-8916-3fbbcfe06244                                                                                                                                              
                     Faulting package full name:                                                                                                                                                                  
                     Faulting package-relative application ID:                                                                                                                                                    
Source             : Application Error                                                                                                                                                                            
ReplacementStrings : {WINWORD.EXE, 15.0.4569.1504, 52c5eccd, KERNELBASE.dll...}                                                                                                                                   
InstanceId         : 1000                                                                                                                                                                                         
TimeGenerated      : 12/5/2016 1:52:25 PM                                                                                                                                                                         
TimeWritten        : 12/5/2016 1:52:25 PM                                                                                                                                                                         
UserName           :                                                                                                                                                                                              
Site               :                                                                                                                                                                                              
Container          :
```

Content of the Report.wer file which was attached to the error event

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131254397111571055
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131254397117750833
ReportIdentifier=00af6f34-bb21-11e6-a94c-c1ade9024feb
IntegratorReportIdentifier=f48b4b89-7ac0-4b8b-8714-5827be5c2a54
WOW64=1
NsAppName=WINWORD.EXE
AppSessionGuid=000056c0-0390-0014-0d3e-cec22d4fd201
TargetAppId=W:0000da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709!0000da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709!WINWORD.EXE
TargetAppVer=2016//09//27:07:41:29!1e4b16!WINWORD.EXE
BootId=4294967295
Response.BucketId=294fbccdff50bb44d2891850764ece57
Response.BucketTable=1
Response.LegacyBucketId=108548871343
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=WINWORD.EXE
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=15.0.4871.1000
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=57ea22a9
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=10.0.14393.321
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=57f4c291
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c06d007e
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=000da6f2
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.14393.2.0.0.400.8
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=2beb
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=2beba6fb4680d73a8c78ca7c24ccdb46
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=34b8
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=34b85e01dbe9529312a819250a584bb2
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\WINWORD.EXE
UI[5]=Check online for a solution (recommended)
UI[6]=Check for a solution later (recommended)
UI[7]=Close
UI[8]=Microsoft Word stopped working and was closed
UI[9]=A problem caused the application to stop working correctly. Windows will notify you if a solution is available.
UI[10]=&Close
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\WINWORD.EXE
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\AppVIsvSubsystems32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\MSVCR100.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\AppVIsvStream32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\c2r32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\wwlib.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.14393.321_none_baab3cb4359688b4\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\oart.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\MSVCP100.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office15\mso.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msi.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.447_none_89c64d28dafea4b9\Comctl32.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office15\MSPTLS.DLL
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d10warp.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Microsoft Word
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\WINWORD.EXE
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=BA43D6538E2E0AA779B61DB4AA39A3A7
MetadataHash=-627680739
```

I have read a lot of information. But most of sollutions are about full Windows versions and are using mostly GUI.

I would like to ask advice about what can be a reason of such error? How I can troubleshoot using Powershell remote connection to the Docker container?

Thank you in advance!

PS: Output of ‘docker version’ command:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Comment: are you installing 64-bit office? I think the default install is 32-bit, which I don't believe is supported in containers, but beyond that my guess here would be that the docker container doesn't support all the low-level features word expects to be present, even when it's just loading the COM object and not the gui, in fact I'm not even able to find information about running word in the full install of server core.